# How to cite with biblatex in spanish with english quotes?

Tags: biblatex, citing, babel

I'm making an essay in Spanish, so I use `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` and `\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}` with `biber` for bibliography. Everything does what it should, but when citing, style required `""` become `«»`. I understand this is the "correct" behavior in Spanish typography, but, for unknown reasons, I'm being required to use `""`.

For example, I want the reference:

```
Pérez, Juán. «La Historia de Algo». Madrid: Alguna Editora, 2013.
```

to appear as:

```
Pérez, Juán. "La Historia de Algo". Madrid: Alguna Editora, 2013.
```

and cites without author that appear like:

```
(«Título de Obra Sin Autor»)
```

to appear as:

```
("Título de Obra Sin Autor")
```

I've already tried `\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}` and `\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}`, but I'm not sure if `babel` is the one I should modify.

Comment: You're right. The RAE (_Real Academia Española_) [recommend](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=SSTAZ5sDyD6h59vijX) `«»` for quotes, whereas `“”` and `‘’` should be used for the nested quotes. The "unknown reason" is the absence of `«` and `»` keys, so many people do not know how to write, or worse, they are so accustomed to `""` that they think that this is the correct quotation mark. But this is not a valid reason. 
The best is to ignore the requirement and make it clear that this is the right way. This may hurt the pride of some ignorant, but that is beyond the scope of typography. `:)`

Comment: The thing is that my note depends of _strictly_ following a manual they gave me... Should I sacrifice a decimal point for typography's sake, or try to notify the people behind the manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `csquotes` package with `biblatex`.

Biblatex manual says (p.4):

> csquotes : If this package is available, biblatex will use its language sensitive quotation facilities to enclose certain titles in quotation marks. If not, biblatex uses quotes suitable for American English as a fallback. When writing in any other language, loading csquotes is strongly recommended.

Concretely, add

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}
```

In your case, you want Spanish style reference *but* with English style quotation marks. The second line should produce this result.